# How copy data from Excel to a table using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any alternative way to copy the data from Excel sheet and paste it into a table using Oracle SQL Developer!?

For now I am using (PL/SQL Developer) by writing (for update) at the end of the select statement, Ex:

```
Select * from ABD
for update
```

Then paste the columns from Excel to the table...

Regards
Adel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not exactly copy and paste but you can import data from Excel using Oracle SQL Developer.

Navigate to the table you want to import the data into and click on the `Data` tab.

After clicking on the data tab you should notice a drop down that says `Actions...`
[image: indicating the position of the Data tab and Actions... drop down]

Click `Actions...` and select the bottom option `Import Data...`

Then just follow the wizard to select the correct sheet, and columns that you want to import.

**EDIT :** ***To view the data tab :***

1. Select the `SCHEMA` where your table is created.(Choose from the Connections tab on the left pane).
2. Right click on the `SCHEMA` and choose `SCHEMA BROWSER`.
3. Select your table from the list (by giving your schema).
4. Now you will see the `DATA` tab.
5. Click on `Actions` and `Import Data...`

Comment: still have to pre define the columns... very annoy

Answer (score 4):

None of these options show up for me. The way to **paste** data from Excel is as follows:

- Add an extra column to the left of your spreadsheet data (if you
  don't have row numbers showing in PL/SQL Developer you may not have
  to have an extra empty column to the left).
- Copy the rows of data from your spreadsheet including the empty
  column.
- In PL/SQL Developer, open your table in edit mode. You can
  right-click the table name in the object browser and select Edit Data
  or write your own select statement that includes the rowid and click
  the lock icon. Be sure your columns are ordered the same as in your
  spreadsheet.
- Here's the part that took me forever to figure out: click on the left
  side of the first empty row to highlight it. It will not work if you
  don't have the first empty row highlighted.
- Paste as usual using Ctrl+V or right-click Paste.

I couldn't find this info anywhere when I needed it, so I wanted to be sure to post it.

Comment: Please see the above edited answer for viewing `DATA` tab

Answer (score 1):

You may directly right-click on the table name - that also shows the "Import Data.." option.Then you can follow few simple steps & succeed.

Do anyone know how to import a new table with data from excel?

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of a question inside an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Tables" in "Connections" window, choose "Import data ...", follow the wizard and you will be asked for name for new table.

Answer (score -1):

For PLSQL version 9.0.0.1601

1. From the context menu of the Table, choose "Edit Data"
2. Insert or edit the data
3. Post change